# Hide particular choice option

Tags: list, javascript, choice-field

I have a SharePoint list which has a choice filed. Choices are A, B, C.

Is there anyway I can hide B from the users. I don't want to delete the B option I just want to hide it from users.

Regards

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? Do you have access to content editor/script editor webpart? Do you want to hide this from all users or based on permissions?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Content Editor/Script Editor webpart then you can use JavaScript code, something like:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
       //Hide all options
       $(":input[title^='Choice Column Name']").find("option").hide();

       //Only show selective options
       $(":input[title^='Choice Column Name']").find("option[value='A']").show();
       $(":input[title^='Choice Column Name']").find("option[value='C']").show();

       //OR --> Only hide selective options
       $(":input[title^='Choice Column Name']").find("option[value='B']").hide();
    });
</script>
```

**Reference**: [How to hide certain choice values from appearing in a sharepoint list drop-down?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/244900/how-to-hide-certain-choice-values-from-appearing-in-a-sharepoint-list-drop-down)

If you are using SharePoint online then you can customize list for using Power Apps. You can set source items of your choice field to something like:

```
ClearCollect(colDropDownOptions, Filter(Choices('DataSource'.ColumnOptions), Not(Value = "B")))
```

**Reference**: [How to hide an option in drop down with SharePointIntegration?](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-hide-an-option-in-drop-down-with-SharePointIntegration/td-p/94183)

Comment: Hi @Harris, does this answers your question? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.